# Como pegar uma propriedade de um objeto em uma Session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

No meu `Controller`, tenho uma `ActionResult` responsável por fazer o login do usuário:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Valida(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
{
    oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.SingleOrDefault(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha);

    if (oUsuario == null)
        {
            Session["usuario"] = "Senha ou usuário incorretos";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["usuario"] = oUsuario;
            return RedirectToAction("BPAC");
        }
    }
```

Nessa linha: `Session["usuario"] = oUsuario;` eu informo que na minha sessão eu tenho armazenado um objeto do tipo `Usuario`.

Como eu faço pra mostrar alguma propriedade dele na `View`? Tentei assim: `@Session["usuario"].usuario1` mas não foi. Recebi o erro abaixo:

> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'usuario1' and no extension method 'usuario1' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O uso de objetos em Session necessita utilizar um Cast.

Segue uma das formas no exemplo abaixo:

```
@{var user = Session["Usuario"] as Usuario;}            
<h1>@user.Email</h1>
```

Segue o código funcionando no .NET Fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2YfSQ

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que fazer o casting da session:

```
@{
     var usuario = (Usuario)Session["usuario"];
}
```